# MissingPropertyException in grails

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller, grails-services

I have a problem when I try to show the view of one of my domains. I built a method to sum some quantities, but I have this error and I don't know how to fix it. I understand that the variable awards does not exist, but I have this value in my domain. Here is the code of the only method in the controller that gives me the error.

```
URI /Rewards/customer/show/1
Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message No such property: awards for class: rewards.Customer

Around line 14 of grails-app/services/rewards/CalculationsService.groovy
11: 
12: def getTotalPoints(customerInstance){
13:     def totalAwards = 0
14:     customerInstance.awards.each{
15:         totalAwards = totalAwards + it.points
16:     }
17:     customerInstance.totalPoints = totalAwards

Around line 33 of grails-app/controllers/rewards/CustomerController.groovy
30: 
31: def show(Long id){
32:     def customerInstance = Customer.get(id)
33:     customerInstance = calculationsService.getTotalPoints(customerInstance)
34:     [customerInstance: customerInstance]
35: }
36:
```

CONTROLLER (CustomerController.groovy)

```
package rewards

class CustomerController {
    static scaffold = true

    def calculationsService

    def show(Long id){
        def customerInstance = Customer.get(id)
        customerInstance = calculationsService.getTotalPoints(customerInstance)
        [customerInstance: customerInstance]
    }
```

MODEL COSTUMER

```
class Customer {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Long phone
    String email
    Integer totalPoints
    static hastMany = [awards:Award, orders:OnlineOrder]

    static constraints = {
        phone()
        firstName(nullable: true)
        lastName(nullable: true)
        email(nullable: true, email: true)
        totalPoints(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

MODEL AWARD

```
package rewards

class Award {
    Date awardDate
    String type
    Integer points
    static belongsTo = [customer:Customer]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

SERVICES (CalculationsService.groovy)

```
package rewards

import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class CalculationsService {


    def serviceMethod() {

    }

    def getTotalPoints(customerInstance){
        def totalAwards = 0
        customerInstance.awards.each{
            totalAwards = totalAwards + it.points
        }
        customerInstance.totalPoints = totalAwards
        return customerInstance
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the code of the model Customer?

Comment: MODEL COSTUMER
class Customer {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Long phone
    String email
    Integer totalPoints
    static hastMany = [awards:Award, orders:OnlineOrder]

    static constraints = {
        phone()
        firstName(nullable: true)
        lastName(nullable: true)
        email(nullable: true, email: true)
        totalPoints(nullable: true)
    }
}

Comment: Try running grails clean and see if it helps

Comment: No, I clean the project, but i have the same error

Comment: Did you add the "awards" property recently? By any chance did you insert a Customer on the database without this property? If so, you need to clean the DB

Comment: I add awards to the same time that all the columns in the DB, and everytime that I stop-app and start-app the DB is generate new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've spelled `hasMany` wrong in your Customer domain.

```
static hastMany = [awards:Award, orders:OnlineOrder]
```

should be

```
static hasMany = [awards:Award, orders:OnlineOrder]
```